# How can I remove all traces of my original Gmail address from a “send mail as” alias?

Tags: gmail, email-forwarding, domain

### Background: Forwarding custom domain's email to and from Gmail

I've got a personal Gmail account that I've had for many years at `example@gmail.com`. Of course, the address isn't “example”, it's something I set up on a whim years ago. Now, I've got `myname@mydomain.com` via email forwarding in Namecheap, and would like to use that for all my future professional and public interactions.

### What I've done so far: Email forwarding and Send Mail As

I used Namecheap's domain configuration for “All Host Records” to use their *Free Email Forwarding* option, and added `byname` as the User Name and `example@gmail.com` as the Forwarded To address. I'd like to use Namecheap's email forwarding, as it's super easy, but I'm open to running my own mail server, as long as it, too, forwards mail to and from Gmail.

Then, I set up the `example@gmail.com` account to send mail as `myname@mydomain.com` through *Settings* → *Accounts and Import* → **Send Mail As**, and I've tried this with *Treat as an alias* both set and cleared. The mail gets delivered, and shows that the sender is the `myname@mydomain.com` address, and clicking “reply” populates this address in the “to” field as it should. This is all well and good for 99% of the population.

### What's not working

Unfortunately, showing the original message from within Gmail reveals that the Sender, Return-Path, Received-SPF, and Authentication-Results all contain `example@gmail.com`.

Why is this information leaked? Is this something I should be concerned about? Finally, and most importantly, how can I send mail from my new address and use Gmail as the mail server without leaking the Gmail address?

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem - for me the answer was to not only have the new address added as a "Send mail as:" but also to choose "Send through X's SMTP servers"

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can switch to [Google Apps](https://www.google.com/a/cpanel/standard/new3?hl=en&source=gafb-pricing-tabletop-en) (free). This lets you have a Google account on your domain name, with Gmail working directly. You'd have to use that new account for Gmail (and migrate your old emails in, if desired), but it would be a total Google solution.

Comment: Note: since 2013 Google Apps is not free anymore.